# Rails - post form with ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have some ajax that is POSTing data to a URL, and I can see Chrome sending off the data :

```
Request URL:http://ubuntu:3000/groups?authenticity_token=EjAsrE07jziAMLt918Mgid4PSpRFfjIaz%2Bd9ZCxmbTo%3D

Request Payload
{"object":{"name":"test","description":"testing","is_era":false,"unique_ui_identifier":"db3772f13e8c5ec958105c72f11b7b89"}}
```

I then look at the dev logs, and the server shows the following:

```
Started POST "/groups?authenticity_token=EjAsrE07jziAMLt918Mgid4PSpRFfjIaz%2Bd9ZCxmbTo%3D" for 192.168.222.1 at Mon Aug 26 10:46:19 +0930 2013
Processing by GroupsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"group"=>{}, "authenticity_token"=>"EjAsrE07jziAMLt918Mgid4PSpRFfjIaz+d9ZCxmbTo="}
```

So, the server doesn't seem to be receiving the POST data. i.e. the 'object' with name/description/etc.
A few things I find strange:

- It seems to be receiving an empty 'group' hash, but I have no idea where this would be coming from.
- Is this strange: 'Processing by GroupsController#create as */*'...what is the */* ?

If anyone can help me, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Should'nt the Reguest Payload contain "group" instead of "object" ?

Comment: it doesn't matter what it's called, the same thing happens. Event if it's 'group'.